# getView in gridview called multi-times

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

I have a grid view that show some items, in getView I need to increase the number of views on each item , what happen that getView() is called muti-times for the same item

how to make sure that my increment views method will called only one time ?

Comment: Only for the first few items isnt it? You have to live with that.

Comment: @greenapps yes , but it gives me unreal statistics about item views, is there any way to fix this problem

Comment: `You have to live with that.`.

Comment: You can't base and kind of logic or calculations on the number of times or in which order an `Adapter`'s `getView()` method is called. The `AdapterView` (`GridView`, in your case) can call that method an indeterminable number of times for any given position; e.g., for layout calculations, scrollbar and thumb sizings, etc. If you really need to count when a particular item scrolls on/off-screen, it'll take some work.